# How to convert Lambda Expression query in to Sql Query?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, lambda, azure-sql-database

I am dynamically generating Lambda expression, have a requirement to cross check the Lambda expression query is correct or not. It means how the lambda expression execute against Entity framework, and how it converts in to sqlquery internally? I am using Windows Azure Sqlserver. Dont have any idea about SQL Profiler supports for window Azure Sqlserver.

**Lambda expression query applied in Entity framework**

```
IQueryable<Object> queryResults = null;

queryEntity = _db.Companies.Where(Company => ((Convert(Company.Name) == "test")
```

Or

```
((Convert(Company.AddressLine1) == "test1") Or (Convert(Company.AddressLine2) == "test2"))));
```

Anybody have Ideas? Please share.

Comment: If you want to know how to Query with Lambda Expression to the Entity Framework I can give you here an example.

Comment: No I am not looking for this.  I m getting results like below                                                            Lambda expression ---> Entity framework Execution ---> SqLserver db.     I would like to know How the Lambda expression query converts in to SQLQuery before execute against SQLServer DB.

Comment: yeah that's what I am talking about. Are you using MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution from this Link, Azure Sql profiler, I am ble to see the SQL query for my lambda expression.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benko/archive/2012/05/19/cloudtip-14-how-do-i-get-sql-profiler-info-from-sql-azure.aspx